# How to pass an empty value as a prop on a Material UI button

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using a ternary operator in a prop for a button.  It works fine, but I am getting a warning in the browser about the empty string and wanted to know if there is a better way to do this so I don't get an error.

```
<Button
    variant={activeButton === 'credit card' ? 'outlined' : 'contained'}
    //This terniary operator is throwing a warning in the console because MUI desn't like the empty string
    color={activeButton === 'credit card' ? 'primary' : ''}
    onClick={() => setActiveButton('credit card')}
>
    Credit Card
</Button>;
```

[Image of console warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdSnK.png)

Answer (score 1):

Use `undefined` instead of empty string:

`color={activeButton === 'credit card' ? 'primary' : undefined}`

Passing `undefined` is equivalent to omitting the prop entirely and will allow the default for that prop (if [defined within the component](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.8.3/packages/material-ui/src/Button/Button.js#L267)) to be applied.